sf methods to delineate a centerline from a channel
I am hoping to use Voronoi method to delineate a river channel centerline. I came across multiple sources but failed to replicate the work due to retired pacakges (rgeos).
i.e. https://gist.github.com/FloodHydrology/829d3846f0722610ff69d896ad65af3e
Identify a linear feature on a raster map and return a linear shape object using R
library(sf)
library(tibble)
library(sf)

channel <- st_as_sf(tribble(
  ~x, ~y,
  656873.7, 5553711,
  656993.1, 5553738,
  656993.6, 5553738,
  656994.1, 5553738,
  656994.6, 5553738,
  656995.1, 5553738,
  656995.7, 5553738,
  656996.2, 5553738,
  656996.7, 5553738,
  656997.2, 5553738,
  656997.7, 5553738,
  656998.2, 5553738,
  656998.7, 5553738,
  656999.2, 5553738,
  656999.7, 5553737,
  657000.2, 5553737,
  657000.6, 5553737,
  657001.0, 5553737,
  657001.5, 5553736,
  657001.9, 5553736,
  657002.3, 5553736,
  657002.6, 5553735,
  657003.0, 5553735,
  657003.3, 5553734,
  657003.6, 5553734,
  657126.8, 5553550,
  657127.0, 5553550,
  657127.3, 5553549,
  657127.5, 5553549,
  657127.7, 5553548,
  657127.9, 5553548,
  657128.1, 5553548,
  657128.2, 5553547,
  657128.3, 5553546,
  657128.4, 5553546,
  657128.4, 5553545,
  657128.4, 5553545,
  657129.8, 5553466,
  657129.8, 5553465,
  657129.7, 5553465,
  657129.7, 5553464,
  657129.6, 5553464,
  657129.5, 5553463,
  657129.4, 5553463,
  657129.2, 5553462,
  657129.0, 5553462,
  657128.8, 5553461,
  657128.6, 5553461,
  657128.3, 5553460,
  657128.1, 5553460,
  657127.8, 5553459,
  657127.4, 5553459,
  657127.1, 5553459,
  657126.7, 5553458,
  657126.4, 5553458,
  657126.0, 5553458,
  656995.2, 5553355,
  656971.7, 5553303,
  656975.2, 5553281,
  657061.9, 5553229,
  657233.8, 5553179,
  657234.3, 5553179,
  657234.8, 5553179,
  657235.3, 5553179,
  657235.9, 5553178,
  657236.3, 5553178,
  657312.0, 5553130,
  657312.5, 5553130,
  657312.9, 5553130,
  657313.3, 5553129,
  657313.7, 5553129,
  657314.1, 5553128,
  657314.5, 5553128,
  657314.8, 5553128,
  657315.1, 5553127,
  657315.4, 5553127,
  657315.6, 5553126,
  657315.9, 5553126,
  657316.1, 5553125,
  657316.2, 5553125,
  657406.2, 5552837,
  657467.5, 5552813,
  657534.9, 5552855,
  657535.4, 5552855,
  657535.9, 5552855,
  657536.3, 5552855,
  657536.8, 5552855,
  657537.3, 5552856,
  657537.8, 5552856,
  657538.3, 5552856,
  657538.8, 5552856,
  657539.4, 5552856,
  657539.9, 5552856,
  657540.4, 5552856,
  657540.9, 5552856,
  657541.4, 5552856,
  657542.0, 5552856,
  657542.5, 5552856,
  657543.0, 5552856),
  coords = c("x", "y")) %>% 
  st_combine() %>% 
  st_cast("LINESTRING") 

channel <- st_buffer(channel, 100)

st_voronoi(channel) %>% 
  st_collection_extract()

I got as far as :

But not sure how to use the edges of the Voronoi object to obtain centerpoints, then centerlines.

Are you sure this is the tessellation from st_voronoi(channel) and channel is the result of your reprex? If yes, then how are you plotting it and what versions of sf and GEOS (sf::sf_extSoftVersion()) are you currently using? What I'd expect you to have is something like this - https://i.sstatic.net/w4fxB.png - where a set of Voronoi polygon edges form kind of a center line along the stream shape.

Hi @margusl - confirming I get the same result as you when plotting in R. Original image was made in QGIS with the Voronoi output which was inaccurate. Any insight on how I can continue with the delineation as a next step?

Do you need to use the voronoi method yourself? There's the centerline package that seems to do it for you. A quick test on your data looks pretty good.  https://github.com/atsyplenkov/centerline

Here's a simplified approach just to illustrate general workflow, though for the actual task, the centerline package suggested in comments might save you a ton of time and you'd probably get better results, too.
Suitability of Voronoi tesselation for centerline detection depends highly on vertex density of the shape and vertex distribution, so here I'm just adding more points, in the first example with st_line_sample() (uniform distribution, nice for visualization, might miss some critical points at bends), and in the 2nd example with st_segmentize() (probably introduces some artefacts at centerline ends).
As we are after Vornoi edges and do not really care about polygons, we can go wiht st_voronoi(... , bOnlyEdges = TRUE)
From the resulting edges, we are only interested in those that are within the channel polygon, so we can use a spatial filter to remove most (but likely not all) of the clutter. From there, we can think of it as a graph problem -- centerline is the longest geodesic, the graph diameter.
tidygraph / igarph and sf are neatly brought together in sfnetworks package, which lets us conveniently convert our sf object of remaining Voronoi edges to a graph. And after graph processing, we can convert it back to sf.
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.2, GDAL 3.6.2, PROJ 9.2.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(dplyr)
library(sfnetworks)
library(tidygraph)
library(ggplot2)

# uniform point distribution along polygon line 
# for simplification & visualization
edge_points <-
  channel %>% 
  st_cast("LINESTRING") %>% 
  st_line_sample(density = 0.02) %>% 
  st_union()
edge_points
#> Geometry set for 1 feature 
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 656774.6 ymin: 5552713 xmax: 657642.6 ymax: 5553838
#> CRS:           NA
#> MULTIPOINT ((656930.3 5553621), (656880.9 55536...

# we can set bOnlyEdges to get edges instead of polygons
vor_edges <- 
  st_voronoi(edge_points, bOnlyEdges = TRUE) %>% 
  # from single MULTILINESTRING to a set of LINESTRINGs
  st_cast("LINESTRING")
vor_edges
#> Geometry set for 183 features 
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 655649.7 ymin: 5551588 xmax: 658767.4 ymax: 5554963
#> CRS:           NA
#> First 5 geometries:
#> LINESTRING (655649.7 5554589, 656873.7 5553711)
#> LINESTRING (656873.7 5553711, 656873.7 5553711)
#> LINESTRING (656873.7 5553711, 656873.7 5553711)
#> LINESTRING (656873.7 5553711, 655649.7 5553857)
#> LINESTRING (656873.7 5553711, 656873.6 5553711)

# keep only edges within channel
edge_within <- 
  vor_edges %>% 
  # for convenience of st_filter we need to convert sfc to sf
  st_sf() %>% 
  st_filter(channel, .predicate = st_within) 
edge_within
#> Simple feature collection with 68 features and 0 fields
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 656873.6 ymin: 5552816 xmax: 657543.1 ymax: 5553731
#> CRS:           NA
#> First 10 features:
#>                          geometry
#> 1  LINESTRING (656873.7 555371...
#> 2  LINESTRING (656873.7 555371...
#> 3  LINESTRING (656873.7 555371...
#> 4  LINESTRING (656996.3 555330...
#> 5  LINESTRING (656997.3 555329...
#> 6  LINESTRING (656873.8 555371...
#> 7  LINESTRING (656873.8 555371...
#> 8  LINESTRING (656996.6 555330...
#> 9  LINESTRING (656900.8 555371...
#> 10 LINESTRING (656900.8 555371...

# to remove edges that are not part of the centre line, 
# yet are too short to intersect with channel polygon outline, 
# we can convert the remaining list of edges to a graph, 
# keep only nodes (and edges) that are part of a graph diameter (longest geodesic),  
# remove pseudo nodes (nodes with 2 incident edges) with to_spatial_smooth morpher and 
# convert resulting graph to a single LINESTRING
channel_cline <- 
  edge_within %>% 
  as_sfnetwork(directed = FALSE) %>% 
  activate(nodes) %>% 
  # get_diameter returns a list node tbl indices, so we can use it with slice
  slice(igraph::get_diameter(.) %>% as.vector()) %>% 
  convert(to_spatial_smooth) %>%
  st_as_sf(active = "edges")
channel_cline
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 3 fields
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 656873.6 ymin: 5552831 xmax: 657543.1 ymax: 5553725
#> CRS:           NA
#> # A tibble: 1 × 4
#>    from    to .tidygraph_edge_index                                     geometry
#>   <int> <int> <list>                                                <LINESTRING>
#> 1     1     2 <int [63]>            (656873.6 5553711, 656873.7 5553711, 656873…


# visualize previous steps ---------------------------------------------------
# cropped variant for plot
vor_crop <- st_crop(vor_edges, st_buffer(channel, 100))

p1 <- ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = channel, fill = "lightblue") +
  geom_sf(data = edge_points) +
  # Calssify edges (within / not within channel polygon)
  geom_sf(data = vor_crop, aes(color = st_within(vor_crop, channel, sparse = FALSE)), show.legend = FALSE) +
  ggtitle("Vor. edges from \nunif. sampled points") +
  theme_void() 

p2 <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = channel, fill = "lightblue") +
  geom_sf(data = edge_within) +
  ggtitle("Vor. edges within \nchannel poly") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.title.position = "top")

p3 <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = channel, fill = "lightblue") +
  geom_sf(data = channel_cline) +
  ggtitle("Longest geodesic\n") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.title.position = "top")

patchwork::wrap_plots(p1, p2, p3)


As st_voronoi works with a polygon, we can just add some vertex density to that channel edge with st_segmentize(), so in a single pipeline it might look something like this:
cline_sfc <- 
  channel %>% 
  # we can add more points to the polygon outline and pass it directly to st_voronoi
  st_segmentize(dfMaxLength = 10) %>%
  st_voronoi(bOnlyEdges = TRUE) %>% 
  st_cast("LINESTRING") %>% 
  st_sf() %>% 
  st_filter(channel, .predicate = st_within) %>%
  as_sfnetwork(directed = FALSE) %>% 
  activate(nodes) %>% 
  slice(igraph::get_diameter(.) %>% as.vector()) %>% 
  # there's a good chance that there are few artefacts at the beginning and end,
  # naive but perhaps good enough approach would be just to remove few nodes
  # from both ends of the diameter list:
  # slice(igraph::get_diameter(.) %>% as.vector() %>% head(-2) %>% tail(-2)) %>% 
  convert(to_spatial_smooth) %>%
  st_as_sf(active = "edges") %>%
  st_geometry() 
  
cline_sfc
#> Geometry set for 1 feature 
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 656873.7 ymin: 5552826 xmax: 657553.8 ymax: 5553729
#> CRS:           NA
#> LINESTRING (656873.7 5553711, 656873.7 5553711,...

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = channel, fill = "lightblue") +
  geom_sf(data = cline_sfc) +
  ggtitle("cline_sfc") +
  theme_void() 


Input shape:
channel <- st_as_sf(tribble(
  ~x, ~y,
  656873.7, 5553711,
  656993.1, 5553738,
  656993.6, 5553738,
  656994.1, 5553738,
  656994.6, 5553738,
  656995.1, 5553738,
  656995.7, 5553738,
  656996.2, 5553738,
  656996.7, 5553738,
  656997.2, 5553738,
  656997.7, 5553738,
  656998.2, 5553738,
  656998.7, 5553738,
  656999.2, 5553738,
  656999.7, 5553737,
  657000.2, 5553737,
  657000.6, 5553737,
  657001.0, 5553737,
  657001.5, 5553736,
  657001.9, 5553736,
  657002.3, 5553736,
  657002.6, 5553735,
  657003.0, 5553735,
  657003.3, 5553734,
  657003.6, 5553734,
  657126.8, 5553550,
  657127.0, 5553550,
  657127.3, 5553549,
  657127.5, 5553549,
  657127.7, 5553548,
  657127.9, 5553548,
  657128.1, 5553548,
  657128.2, 5553547,
  657128.3, 5553546,
  657128.4, 5553546,
  657128.4, 5553545,
  657128.4, 5553545,
  657129.8, 5553466,
  657129.8, 5553465,
  657129.7, 5553465,
  657129.7, 5553464,
  657129.6, 5553464,
  657129.5, 5553463,
  657129.4, 5553463,
  657129.2, 5553462,
  657129.0, 5553462,
  657128.8, 5553461,
  657128.6, 5553461,
  657128.3, 5553460,
  657128.1, 5553460,
  657127.8, 5553459,
  657127.4, 5553459,
  657127.1, 5553459,
  657126.7, 5553458,
  657126.4, 5553458,
  657126.0, 5553458,
  656995.2, 5553355,
  656971.7, 5553303,
  656975.2, 5553281,
  657061.9, 5553229,
  657233.8, 5553179,
  657234.3, 5553179,
  657234.8, 5553179,
  657235.3, 5553179,
  657235.9, 5553178,
  657236.3, 5553178,
  657312.0, 5553130,
  657312.5, 5553130,
  657312.9, 5553130,
  657313.3, 5553129,
  657313.7, 5553129,
  657314.1, 5553128,
  657314.5, 5553128,
  657314.8, 5553128,
  657315.1, 5553127,
  657315.4, 5553127,
  657315.6, 5553126,
  657315.9, 5553126,
  657316.1, 5553125,
  657316.2, 5553125,
  657406.2, 5552837,
  657467.5, 5552813,
  657534.9, 5552855,
  657535.4, 5552855,
  657535.9, 5552855,
  657536.3, 5552855,
  657536.8, 5552855,
  657537.3, 5552856,
  657537.8, 5552856,
  657538.3, 5552856,
  657538.8, 5552856,
  657539.4, 5552856,
  657539.9, 5552856,
  657540.4, 5552856,
  657540.9, 5552856,
  657541.4, 5552856,
  657542.0, 5552856,
  657542.5, 5552856,
  657543.0, 5552856),
  coords = c("x", "y")) %>% 
  st_combine() %>% 
  st_cast("LINESTRING") 

channel <- st_buffer(channel, 100)

